# ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]]

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am fetching documents from Elastic Search index named as `replacement_local100`. I am querying the same index two times.

First Query --> Based on the `code` as input am getting a list of `link_ids`.

The second Query --> Based on `List of Link IDs` (from the first query) I am getting different data and I am using filter too.

When I am invoking the second query I am getting the error:

```
ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=search_phase_execution_exception, reason=all shards failed]]
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:573)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:549)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:456)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:429)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:368)
    at com.jci.vb2.searchengine.dao.ReplacementDao.getReplacementByCode(ReplacementDao.java:127)
    at com.jci.vb2.searchengineservice.mqservice.Service.getReplacementByCode(Service.java:73)
    at com.jci.vb2.searchengineservice.mqservice.Consumer.consume(Consumer.java:48)
    at com.jci.vb2.utils.Consumer$1$1.run(Consumer.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [GET], host [http://localhost:9200], URI [/replacement_local100/_search?typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512], status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"term\" : {\n          \"id\" : {\n            \"value\" : \"]\",\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"filter\" : [\n      {\n        \"match\" : {\n          \"product_link_type\" : {\n            \"query\" : \"replacement\",\n            \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n            \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n            \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n            \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n            \"lenient\" : false,\n            \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n            \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}","index_uuid":"yg7rn4njRaKfC6YtraXJPg","index":"replacement_local100"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"replacement_local100","node":"uPLyU7R5RXeirg8XzRqhnA","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"failed to create query: {\n  \"bool\" : {\n    \"must\" : [\n      {\n        \"term\" : {\n          \"id\" : {\n            \"value\" : \"]\",\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"filter\" : [\n      {\n        \"match\" : {\n          \"product_link_type\" : {\n            \"query\" : \"replacement\",\n            \"operator\" : \"OR\",\n            \"prefix_length\" : 0,\n            \"max_expansions\" : 50,\n            \"fuzzy_transpositions\" : true,\n            \"lenient\" : false,\n            \"zero_terms_query\" : \"NONE\",\n            \"auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query\" : true,\n            \"boost\" : 1.0\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    ],\n    \"adjust_pure_negative\" : true,\n    \"boost\" : 1.0\n  }\n}","index_uuid":"yg7rn4njRaKfC6YtraXJPg","index":"replacement_local100","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"]\""}}}]},"status":400}
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:357)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:346)
        at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:177)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436)
        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
        ... 1 more
        Suppressed: java.net.ConnectException
            at org.apache.http.nio.pool.RouteSpecificPool.timeout(RouteSpecificPool.java:168)
            at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool.requestTimeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:561)
            at org.apache.http.nio.pool.AbstractNIOConnPool$InternalSessionRequestCallback.timeout(AbstractNIOConnPool.java:822)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionRequestImpl.timeout(SessionRequestImpl.java:183)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processTimeouts(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:210)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultConnectingIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultConnectingIOReactor.java:155)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:348)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.conn.PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.execute(PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager.java:192)
            at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase$1.run(CloseableHttpAsyncClientBase.java:64)
            ... 1 more
```

Java code below, that I am using to fetch documents from ElasticSearch index.

```
private final String INDEX = "replacement_local100";
private final String TYPE = "doc";
private RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient;
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

public ReplacementDao( ObjectMapper objectMapper, RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    this.restHighLevelClient = restHighLevelClient;
}

 public List<Replacement> getReplacementByCode(String code, String regionId, String countryCode, String companyId){
     System.out.println("replacement service...."+code);
    try {
              if (restHighLevelClient != null) {
                  restHighLevelClient.close();
              }
          } catch (final Exception e) {
              logger.info("Error closing ElasticSearch client: ");
          }

          try {
              restHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(
                      RestClient.builder(
                              new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                              new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
          } catch (Exception e) {
              logger.info(e.getMessage());
          }


            SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
            SearchRequest searchRequest2 = new SearchRequest(INDEX); 
            searchRequest.types(TYPE);
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder2 = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", code);

            searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);
            searchSourceBuilder.size(50);
            searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
            SearchResponse searchResponse1 = null;
            try {
                 searchResponse1 = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            SearchHit[] searchHits1 = searchResponse1.getHits().getHits();
            System.out.println("Hits size--->"+searchHits1.length);
            Replacement linkId = null;
            Replacement replacement = null;
            List<Replacement> linkIDList=new ArrayList<Replacement>();
            for (SearchHit hit1 : searchHits1) {
                linkId = new Replacement();
                 Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap1 = hit1.getSourceAsMap();
                 linkId.setLink_id((Integer) sourceAsMap1.get("link_id"));
                 linkIDList.add(linkId);
            }

            System.out.println("Link ID List Size --->"+linkIDList.size());
            for(Replacement link_id:linkIDList) {
                System.out.println("Link ID List --->"+link_id.getLink_id()+"  Type--->"+link_id.getType());
            }

                    QueryBuilder qb2=null;
                    List<Integer> link_id_array=new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    for(Replacement link_id:linkIDList) {
                        link_id_array.add(link_id.getLink_id());
                    }

                    qb2 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                            .must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("id", link_id_array))
                            .filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("product_link_type", "replacement"));


                    searchSourceBuilder2.query(qb2);
                    searchSourceBuilder2.size(50);
                    searchRequest2.source(searchSourceBuilder2);
                    System.out.println("Request 2 --->"+searchRequest2);
                    SearchResponse searchResponse2 = null;
                    try {
                         searchResponse2 = restHighLevelClient.search(searchRequest2); // Am getting error on this line
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.getLocalizedMessage();
                    }
                    List<Replacement> replacementList=new ArrayList<Replacement>();
                    SearchHit[] searchHits2 = searchResponse2.getHits().getHits();
                    for (SearchHit hit2 : searchHits2) {
                        Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap2 = hit2.getSourceAsMap();
                        replacement=new Replacement();
                        replacement.setId(sourceAsMap2.get("id").toString());
                        replacement.setCode(sourceAsMap2.get("code").toString());
                        replacementList.add(replacement);
                      }
```

Can you pleasee help me in figuring out what am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
.must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("id", link_id_array))
```

You need to use a `terms` query instead since you're passing a list of IDs

```
.must(QueryBuilders.termsQuery("id", link_id_array))
                        ^
                        |
                  change this
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had missed adding the @Field annotation on each data member in the ES Entity. Adding that removed this error.